# Sql Delete trigger multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a trigger to several lines but I do not know how I can do it already I tried to search but I only managed to get to that code that is there, I would like to know if anyone can help me. Thank you.

```
Create Trigger UXExcelFile_DELETE on UXExcelFile 
after delete
AS
Begin
Set nocount on 
Declare @TransDate date
Declare @TransTime Time(7)
Declare  @CardNo  varchar(255)
Declare @VoucherNo varchar(255)
Declare @Quantity varchar(150)
Declare @TransactionValue varchar(150)
Declare @Morada varchar(255)

select @TransDate =deleted.TransDate,@TransTime=deleted.TransTime,@CardNo = deleted.CardNo, @VoucherNo = deleted.VoucherNo, @Quantity = deleted.Quantity, @TransactionValue = deleted.TransactionValue, @Morada = deleted.Morada from deleted

Insert into UXExcelFileTrigger (TransDate,TransTime,CardNo,VoucherNo,Quantity,TransactionValue,Morada)values(@TransDate,@TransTime,@CardNo,@VoucherNo,@Quantity,@TransactionValue,@Morada)

END
```

Comment: This is not MySQL code.  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another, one that has more information on the data structure and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested the code, but I think it will be something like this:

```
Create Trigger UXExcelFile_DELETE on UXExcelFile 
after delete
AS
Begin
Set nocount on 

Insert into UXExcelFileTrigger (TransDate,TransTime,CardNo,VoucherNo,Quantity,TransactionValue,Morada)
    SELECT TransDate, TransTime, CardNo, VoucherNo, Quantity, TransactionValue, Morada
    FROM deleted

END
```